# Running Jmeter Scripts in distribution breakdown percentage in single flow of 3 scripts

Tags: performance, web-services, jmeter

I have a 3 Test Script of Jmeter.I have to run in single flow all these three scripts and their % breakdown like : 1. 15%, 2. 65%, 3. 20%.

How can we run it in Jmeter?

Comment: There's a gazillion ways to achieve percentage breakdown: by setting users, iterations, Throughput controller, all concurrent operations are the same, or random, or different, etc, etc. So you've got to be more specific: what's your current Test plan looks like and what kind of breakdown do you want to achieve

Comment: i have created 3 different test plans. each test plan is basically a workflow that involves multiple web-service calls. my aim is to distribute users among these 3 test plans - for example if i am setting active users to 100 and i want 10% for 1st workflow, 70% for 2nd and 20% for 3rd workflow. all the 3 workflow should execute in parallel, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest instead of creating three different test plan you can have below structure

[image: Tree structure]

Comment: can you please again attach the image of structure.I am not able to view